# How to append and run JavaScript/jQuery animations on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, css-animations

In my code below I am creating two canvas tags and appending them to the body. The animation is designed to drawn a check. On page load, both canvas tags are appended to the page, but only one check is drawn.

```js
var start = 100;
var mid = 145;
var end = 250;
var width = 22;
var leftX = start;
var leftY = start;
var rightX = mid - (width / 2.7);
var rightY = mid + (width / 2.7);
var animationSpeed = 20;

function draw(ctx){

  for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++){

  var canvas = $("<canvas height='200'/>")
  $("body").prepend(canvas);
  var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[j].getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = width;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 150, 0, 1)';

  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 150, 0, 1)';
}

for (i = start; i < mid; i++) {
    var drawLeft = window.setTimeout(function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(start, start);
        ctx.lineTo(leftX, leftY);
        ctx.stroke();
        leftX++;
        leftY++;
    }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
}

for (i = mid; i < end; i++) {
    var drawRight = window.setTimeout(function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(leftX, leftY);
        ctx.lineTo(rightX, rightY);
        ctx.stroke();
        rightX++;
        rightY--;
    }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
  }
}
draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-arranged the code a little.  The crux of it was inserting the `<canvas>` tag with an id that was derived from the loop counter (canvas0, canvas1, ...).

That particular canvas is then located using `document.getElementById("canvas" + i)` and send through the `draw(ctx)` method.

In addition the `leftX`, `leftY`, `rightX`, `rightY` needed to be local variables within the `draw(ctx)` function.

```js
var start = 100;
var mid = 145;
var end = 250;
var width = 22;
var animationSpeed = 20;

jQuery(function($) {
 for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++){
  var canvas = $("<canvas id='canvas" + j + "' height='200'/>")
  $("body").prepend(canvas);
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas' + j).getContext('2d');

  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 150, 0, 1)';

  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 150, 0, 1)';
  
  draw(ctx)
 }
})

function draw(ctx){

 var leftX = start;
 var leftY = start;
 var rightX = mid - (width / 2.7);
 var rightY = mid + (width / 2.7);

 for (i = start; i < mid; i++) {
  var drawLeft = window.setTimeout(function () {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(start, start);
   ctx.lineTo(leftX, leftY);
   ctx.stroke();
   leftX++;
   leftY++;
  }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
 }

 for (i = mid; i < end; i++) {
  var drawRight = window.setTimeout(function () {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(leftX, leftY);
   ctx.lineTo(rightX, rightY);
   ctx.stroke();
   rightX++;
   rightY--;
  }, 1 + (i * animationSpeed) / 3);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```